# How to scroll in htop with iTerm2

Tags: macos, scroll, terminal, iterm, iterm2

I have just installed iTerm2 for my Mac. When i open htop or tmux, i can scroll like normal with the arrow keys, but not with my mouse. This doesn't happen in the normal Mac Terminal. But strangely, when I hover over the rows in htop, it does actually highlight the right row.

Thanks in advance,

Max

Answer (score 0):

Are you running htop locally on the Mac or ssh'ing to a Linux box? If you're running natively on the Mac, be aware that the code on the htop-osx package on Homebrew is an outdated fork; the new code is at http://github.com/hishamhm/htop/ and a new release in in the works.

> But strangely, when I hover over the rows in htop, it does actually highlight the right row.

Simply hovering shouldn't change the highlighting. This probably means that your terminal is sending click events to htop. What happens if you hover over "F1 Help" at the bottom line? It looks like your iTerm2 application is mismanaging ncurses mouse events.

The latest codebase on the official htop Git repository linked above includes support for NCurses 6, which supports not only mouse clicking but also the scroll wheel correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Now possible to install correctly with brew:

```
brew install ncurses
brew install --with-ncurses htop
```

And that will use the right version of Ncurses and you will be able to scroll etc.